# Why does using an unknown username present "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable", not work correctly with bcrypt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, bcrypt

When I present the program with a correct example of a username and password, it works correctly saying 'Success'.

When i present with a correct username but an incorrect password it returns as it should 'Password incorrect'.

However when presenting with the unknown username the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` is returned.

I have already tried using try: except: statements as such:

```
try:
    if user_name is None:
        cursor1.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)""", (user_name, hashedpass))
        accountsdb.commit()
        return("A new account has been created!")
    



    elif hashedpass is None or not bcrypt.checkpw(pass_word.encode('utf-8'), result):
        return 'Password incorrect. Please re-try'
        
    else:
        return ('Success. Welcome {}!'.format(user_name))

except TypeError:
    cursor1.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)""", (user_name, hashedpass))
    accountsdb.commit()
    return("A new account has been created!")
```

but once again this yields the exact same thing as the main code below.

Main code:

```
user_name = input(str('Please enter your username: ')) # these are the inputs i put into the function (use as args)
pass_word = input(str('Please enter your password: '))


salt = bcrypt.gensalt(rounds=12)
hashedpass = bcrypt.hashpw(pass_word.encode('utf-8'), salt)


cursor1.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            username TEXT,
            password TEXT,
            UNIQUE(username));""") 



def database_check(user_name, pass_word):   # function for checking whether entered "username" and "password" is already present in database
    cursor1.execute("""SELECT password 
            FROM users WHERE username=?""",
            (user_name,))
    
    result = cursor1.fetchone()[0]

    try:
        if result is None:
            cursor1.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)""", (user_name, hashedpass))
            accountsdb.commit()
            return("A new account has been created!")
        
   


        elif hashedpass is None or not bcrypt.checkpw(pass_word.encode('utf-8'), result):
            return 'Password incorrect. Please re-try'
            
        else:
            return ('Success. Welcome {}!'.format(user_name))
```

I already understand that fetchone() returns a tuple, and because of course the user is not already in it the database the tuple is being returned empty. I thought using 'None" or the except method for the type error would fix this problem but apparently not.

Hoping someone can direct me to fix this problem so that as intended it will actually add the new username and password to the database through the sql command that was previously shown `cursor1.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)""", (user_name, hashedpass))`.

Thanks you for any help!

Update:

```
if result is not None:
        password_in_db = result[0]

        return ('Success. Welcome {}!'.format(user_name))
        
   
    elif hashedpass is None or not bcrypt.checkpw(pass_word.encode('utf-8'), password_in_db):
            return 'Password incorrect. Please re-try'
            
    else:
        cursor1.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)""", (user_name, hashedpass))
        accountsdb.commit()
        return("A new account has been created!")
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 2):

the line

```
result = cursor1.fetchone()[0]
```

is assuming that the cursor will fetch a result. If the username is not in the db, the fetchone returns None which is not subscriptable( None[0] makes no sense)
instead, split that to 2 parts

```
result=cursor1.fetchone()
if result is not None:
    password_in_db = result[0]
    ....
else:
    #do whatever you have to
```

Edit:
Seeing your code implementation is not correct of what i have given, here is something you might want

```
result=cursor1.fetchone()
hashedpass = hash(password)#your implementation of hashing
if result is None:
    #if no user in database with given data
    cursor1.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)""", (user_name, hashedpass))
    accountsdb.commit()
    return("A new account has been created!")
elif hashedpass != result[0]:
    #if entered password is not same as stored password
    return "Password incorrect. Please re-try"
else:
    #if no error occours, this is successful login
    return f"Welcome, {username}"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have now incorporated that, however then how do i go on about ensuring the password is actually correct. As now the system says 'Success' even when the password is wrong. I've added an update section..

Comment: Buddy, Just look at the code. You have not compared to check if entered password is same as password in db

Comment: nvm managed to fix it mate. thanks for the help